# Using data attributes to change background image of element.

Tags: jquery, html

I try to change the background image of an element with a jQuery function.
Got it working with a Select element but get stucked with radio buttons.

Thanks for any help!

**Works with a select box**

```
<div id="imagechange"></div>

    <select class="logo">
    <option data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image1)">image1</option>
    <option data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image2)">image2</option>
    <option data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image3)">image3</option>
    </select>


    <script>
    $('.logo').on('change', function () {
    $("#logo").css("background-image", ($('option:selected', this).data("image")));
    });
    </script>
```

**Does not work with radio buttons**

```
<div id="imagechange"></div>

<input name="test" class="swatch" type="radio" data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image1)">image1<br>
<input name="test" class="swatch" type="radio" data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image2)">image2<br>
<input name="test" class="swatch" type="radio" data-image="url(http://stackoverflow.com/image3)">image3<br>


<script>
$('.swatch').on('change', function () {
$("#imagechange").css("background-image", ($('.swatch:checked', this).data("image")));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without "this" in your function.

```
$("#imagechange").css("background-image", ($('.swatch:checked').data("image")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using `context` argument incorrectly.

`$('.swatch:checked', this)` is the equivalent of `$(this).find('.swatch:checked')`.

However since `this` is a `swatch` there are no descendents to be found inside a radio and your selector is failing to return any matches.

Personally I would suggest always using `find()` instead of context argument as it is easier to read. There is no performance benefit using the context argument as it will use `find()` internally anyway.

Also, `change()` event for radios only fires on a checked radio, so you should be able to do:

```
$('.swatch').on('change', function () {
   $("#imagechange").css("background-image",$(this).data("image"));
});
```